# How can I tweak the '.ini' settings of Dishonored?

Tags: dishonored

I'm running the Steam version of Dishonored, and I'd like to be able to bind a command to <kbd>F6</kbd> disable HUD.

I've noticed that most people actually recommend changing the *DishonoredInput.ini* file, which I don't have in my Config folder, so I assumed that *DefaultInput.ini* would do it.

However it seems like any tweaks I make to my *DefaultInput.ini* file don't actually have any effect.  I tried disabling the game's startup movies through there unsuccessfully (I eventually disabled them by renaming the movie files themselves, so I'm good there), and now I'm trying to include this line to disable HUD:

`.m_PCBindings=(Name="F6",Command="ShowHUD_True")`

But it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Backup the `DefaultInput.ini` file and then rename it to `DishonoredInput.ini`, see if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me an error - "Failed to find default engine .ini file to retrieve My Documents subdirectory to use. Force quitting."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1: Disable automatic updates.
Steam has so that it does not overwrite the changes you make to the ini files. You can do this by right clicking the game -> Properties -> Updates.

Step 2: Go to
`%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\My Games\Dishonored\DishonoredGame\Config\DishonoredInput.ini`

Step 3: Add
`m_PCBindings=(Name="F6",Command="ShowHUD true")`

Step 4: Press F6
Hide or display HUD.

Notice how the "config" folder in the SteamApps directory has only "Default" as start of ini names.

[image]

Notice how the "config" folder in documents has only "Dishonored" as start of ini names.

[image]

#### Directory Path

Correct Path: `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\My Games\Dishonored\DishonoredGame\Config\DishonoredInput.ini`

Incorrect: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Dishonored\DishonoredGame\Config`

#### Code

Correct Code: `m_PCBindings=(Name="F6",Command="ShowHUD true")`

Incorrect Code: `.m_PCBindings=(Name="F6",Command="ShowHUD true")`

Enjoy and have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked!  I didn't realize there were two different Config folders.  Good to know!